# what kind of amperage does this heater draw?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I can't make sense of this chart.  For the column "Drop 9" with 9kw output, what kind of amperage does the heater draw?

[image: chart]

Here's another diagram if that helps.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device has 3 heater elements - so for the 9kW version, each element produces 3kW of heat.

Your drawing indicates that each element is fed with a 230V supply - so 3kW from 230V requires 13A each.

Now if you refer to the "Circuit breaker" column you'll see that your 9kW device can be supplied by a 3-phase supply with 3 x 16A breakers, or if you connect all 3 elements together to the same single-phase breaker then it must be 50A.

The "Power cable" column appears to be telling you what size cables you need, and the numbers given include the Neutral and Earth/Ground wires.
So if you feed your 9kW device from a 3-phase supply, you need 5-wire cable, each wire 2.5mm<sup>2</sup>, or for a single-phase supply you need 3-wire cable, each wire 10mm<sup>2</sup>.

Comment: You'd use an *n*-wire cable, not *n* cables.